# I cannot deploy to heroku... I am getting an error that my application.scss is not found because heroku is looking for application.css. Any tips?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, sass

When I deploy to heroku open up the logs and load up the server logs. This is the error I am getting...

> ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.

I tried these steps from another post here on stack overflow:

Ok, first thing.

Do you have `config.serve_static_files = true` set in your `production.rb` file under `config/environment` folder.

Since we run behind NGINX, in our case it looks like `config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`

Second thing. Did you do `rails assets:precompile` before the uploading it to the server?

And the third thing is. Have you tried calling your file `application.css.scss`, and redoing the `rails assets:precompile`?

Last, and not least thing. How does your `application.scss` file look like?

Did you remove all those *= and used @import instead for Bootstrap

It is nicely described in the documentation:

Import Bootstrap styles in app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:

> // Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported before bootstrap. @import "bootstrap";

And then it says:

> Make sure the file has .scss extension (or .sass for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a .css file instead. If this file exists, it will be served instead of Sass, so rename it:

> $ mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss Then, remove all the *= require and *= require_tree statements from the Sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.

> Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins and variables.

But none of it worked... I tried ChatGPT but honestly it was mainly telling me the same things... I am missing something and really don't know what...

I am not sure if this was correct but `//= link application.scss` is not in my `manifest.js` file and in my `application.html.erb` I have `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>`. Quite honestly I am not sure where am I going wrong. I initialized the rails app like so `rails new <name> --css=bootstrap --database=postgres`. Afterwards I changed my SCSS files. Because I think the bootstrap flag was causing ruckus so I ended up using boostrap gem and importing bootstrap in my `application.scss`. Now I tried to deploy on heroku and this happened. Also I had a bunch of scripts that were looking for `appliaction.bootstrap.scss`, but then the imports inside could not be found. I tried deleting it and realised I was getting my bootstrap from the gem and `@import 'bootstrap';`. I realised that I didn't need that file nor did I need the scripts and that moved me forward, in this error message game. I feel like I tried almost everything is there someone that knows how to help?

One more thing. The push to Heroku is successful. The build is successful too. It only breaks when I actually go to the page... Same thing was happening with `image_tag` helpers. That was fixed by adding extensions meaning `my_picture.png` instead of just `my_picture`. Maybe foolishly I tried `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.scss", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>` but that made it look for `application.scss.css`, which I cannot use because it is not scss...

Answer (score 0):

Soo the problem was in `manifest.js` file. The path to `application.scss` was wrong. But I added `//= link_tree ../stylesheets` and that worked. Also I added this to my `assets.rb` file.

`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('assets')`
`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app/assets')`
`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('../assets')`

and this to my `production.rb` file.

`config.public_file_server.enabled = true`
`config.assets.css_compressor = :sass`
`config.assets.compile = true`

So that did it!